# Помогите оптимизировать запрос mysql, какие индексы создать

Tags: mysql

Есть запрос

```
SELECT articles.id, articles.name, articles.date_add, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT category.name ORDER BY category.type DESC, category.name SEPARATOR  ", " ) AS catname
FROM articles
INNER JOIN articles_categories ON articles.id = articles_categories.id_articles
LEFT JOIN category ON category.id = articles_categories.id_categories
GROUP BY articles.id
ORDER BY articles.date_add
```

План запроса id
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какие индексы надо создать. Что то не могу разобраться.
Сильно тормозит сортировка, но без нее нельзя

Comment: У таблицы articles сделайте поле cat_id у вас на оборот вроде, или у вас не категории а теги

Comment: Для чего? Статья может быть отнесена к нескольким категориям. И что бы не хранить id через "," и создана таблица articles_categories. Ну я думаю по аналогии с тегами получается

Comment: Категории имеют другую смысловую нагрузку нежели теги, так же и связи строятся по разному, плюс на сайте могут быть как категории так и теги одновременно

Comment: Ну задача остается прежней. Одна статья, много категорий. И проблема именно в сортировке(ORDER BY articles.date_add), если ее убрать, то время выполнения сокращается в разы. Как можно сократить за счет индекса

Comment: @ipbortnikov Попробуйте на `articles` сделать составной индекс `(id, date_add)`. И не понятно почему `articles_categories` (1) клеится жестко, а `category` (2) по LEFT. У вас может быть ситуация что в (1) есть запись и для нее в (2) нет записи ?

Comment: Такой ситуации быть не может. Не знаю зачем так написал, но ситуация даже с INNER не меняется. Составной индекс сделал, но по плану он его не использует

Comment: @ipbortnikov А попробуйте по приколу добавить `where articles.id>0` но тогда кроме плана надо время выполнения сравнивать, выборка всей таблицы по индексу обычно медленнее чем просто прямое сканирование (это конечно если сортировка не делается). Если это ничего не даст, то индекс просто по дате, без id, хотя сомневаюсь, что он его возьмет. больше как то идей и нет :(

Comment: Все точно так же

Comment: @ipbortnikov А попробуйте убрать group by: `SELECT articles.id, articles.name, articles.date_add,
(select GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT category.name ORDER BY category.type DESC, category.name SEPARATOR  ", " )
  from articles_categories join category ON category.id = articles_categories.id_categories
 where articles.id = articles_categories.id_articles)  AS catname
 FROM articles
ORDER BY articles.date_add`

Answer (score 1):

Индексы по полю `date_add` не помогут, т. к. сортировка происходит после группировки. Т. е. сортируется уже новая таблица в памяти, для которой нет индекса по дате.

В вашем случае нужно искать другие подходы для увеличения производительности. Например:

1. Избавтесь от `DISTINCT` в `GROUP_CONCAT`. В вашем случае это лишнее, а на производительность выборки может сильно влиять.
2. Не выбирайте сразу все данные из таблицы. Если в таблицах по несколько миллионов записей, то маловероятно, что вам они нужны все сразу. Добавьте условие, чтобы сократить набор выгружаемых данных.
3. Уберите сортировку из запроса. Сортировать можно во внешнем скрипте и это может быть намного быстрее.
4. Уберите группировку из запроса. Группировать данные также можно во внешнем скрипте. Без группировки вы сможете использовать индексы и ваш запрос будет обрабатываться очень быстро.
5. Уберите категории из запроса и вместе с ними группировку. Категории можно присоединять во внешнем скрипте. Это существенно увеличит производительность запроса.
6. Если ничего не помогает или не подходит, то можно делать кеширующую таблицу и получать данные уже из неё.

Задачу оптимизации нужно решать комплексно - простое добавление индекса может не помочь.

Comment: п. 1. distinct в group_concat, это не distinct по запросу, он быстрый. п. 3 и 4 - внешние скрипты обычно на каком нибудь php - он медленнее будет делать то же самое, а если mysql на отдельном сервере (как на части хостингов) то он еще и объемные данные по сети будет гнать

Comment: п. 3 и 4 - в своё время для эксперимента выгружали данные из базы в память и дальнейшую обработку проводили уже в памяти. Получалось значительно быстрее, чем каждый раз обращаться к базе. Данных было не так много, но mysql их обрабатывал уже с трудом. Некий аналог кеша. Автор поста не указал никаких подробностей про окружение, поэтому можно попробовать п. 3 и 4.

Comment: п. 4 - с объединением несколько _идущих подряд_ строк в одну без проблем справиться даже PHP.

Comment: Они не будут идти подряд, если по ним не отсортировано в запросе

Comment: Так если убрать группировку категорий, то сортировка по индексу будет выполняться очень быстро. Тогда сортируем по дате и id и получаем строки для группировки подряд. Всё будет работать очень быстро.

Comment: Кстати с сортировкой по индексу я не понял mysql. сегодня специально эксперимент делал. В общем, добавление индекса на единственную таблицу в простейшем запросе (тупо `selct * from t order by x`), по столбцу по которому идет order, не влияет на план выполнения запроса. Все равно получаем 'using filesort'