# использование составных индексов

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, запрос, индексы

Есть две таблицы с большим количеством записей:

1. `recipe - id, name, created`
2. `recipe2ingredient - id, recipe, ingredient`

В таблице recipe стоят следующие индексы:

- `IC - BTREE - id, created`
- `CI - BTREE - created, id`
- `C - BTREE - created`

В таблице recipe2ingredient следующие индексы:

- `R - BTREE - recipe`
- `RI - BTREE - recipe, ingredient`

Есть проблема с использованием составных индексов в следующем запросе:

```
SELECT r.id, COUNT(r.id) AS cnt
FROM recipe r
JOIN recipe2ingredient ri ON ri.recipe = r.id AND ri.ingredient IN (1,2)
GROUP BY r.id
ORDER BY cnt DESC, r.created DESC
LIMIT 0, 5
```

Запрос выполняется довольно долго ~2,5 сек.

Сама суть запроса: вытащить первые 5 рецептов, где есть максимальные совпадения с выбранными ингредиентами, а также отсортированные по дате создания.

Например, если ингредиент #1 - лук, а #2 - морковь:

- Рецепт 881 - лук, морковь, картофель (10 января 2019)
- Рецепт 945 - лук, морковь, картофель (8 января 2019)
- Рецепт 567 - морковь, репа, картофель (12 января 2019)
- Рецепт 113 - репа, картофель (13 января)
- Рецепт 456 - картофель (11 января)

Вот что выдает EXPLAIN запроса у таблицы recipe r:

```
id - 1
select_type - SIMPLE
table - r
type - index
possible_keys - PROMARY.C
key - C
key_len - 5
ref - NULL
rows - 4
Extra - Using index: Using temporary
```

у таблицы recipe2ingredient:

```
id - 1
select_type - SIMPLE
table - ri
type - ref
possible_keys - R
key - R
key_len - 9
ref - recipes.r.id
rows - 4
Extra - Using index
```

Сразу скажу, что проблемы не будет если использовать в ORDER BY и в GROUP BY одинаковые поля, например: id или created или id, created. Но мне нужно как в запросе.

Нигде не могу найти ответа, буду рад любой помощи, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ нашел в старой теме. Вывод такой, что ничего здесь уже не поделать, к сожалению. Вот ссылка:
[Помогите оптимизировать запрос mysql, какие индексы создать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/483865/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-mysql-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)